# Can't remove event listener for windows object

Tags: javascript, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I am having a lot of trouble trying to remove an event listener.

I have created a website that relies on JavaScript quite heavily. When you navigate on the website it is basically loading in elements dynamically without a page refresh with template literals.

I have to sometimes load in content and add infinite scroll but also be able to remove that event again.

This is the code I use to handle scroll events:

```
var start  = 30;
var active = true;

function yHandler(elem)
{

    var oHeight = selectElems('content_main', 'i').offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    var hLimit  = yOffset + window.innerHeight;

    if (hLimit >= oHeight - 500 && active === true)
    {

        active = false;
        new requestContent({
            page: GET.page,
            type: returnContentType(GET.page),
            scroll: true,
            start: start
        }, (results) => {
            if(results){
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    active = true;
                    start  = start + 30;;
                }, 400);
                new ContentActive();
            }
        });
    }
}

var scrollRoute = 
    {

    contentScroll: () =>{
        yHandler();
    }
};

var scrollHandler = function(options)
{

    var func = options.func.name;
    var funcOptions = options.func.options;
    var elem = options.elem;
    var flag = options.flag;

    this.events = () => {
        addEvent(elem, 'scroll', ()=>{
            scrollRoute[func](elem, funcOptions);
        }, flag);
    }
    this.clear = () => {
        elem.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollRoute[func](), flag);
    }
}
```

I am using this function to set events

```
function addEvent(obj, type, fn, flag = false) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, flag);
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
        obj[type + fn] = function () {
            obj["e" + type + fn](window.event);
        };
        obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
    } else {
        obj["on" + type] = obj["e" + type + fn];
    }
}
```

I am calling this code from whatever code when I need to set the infinite scroll event

```
new scrollHandler({
    func: {
        'name':'contentScroll',
    },
    elem: window,
    flag: true,
}).events();
```

I am calling this code from whatever code when I need to remove the infinite scroll event but without any luck

```
new scrollHandler({
    func: {
        'name':'contentScroll',
    },
    elem: window,
    flag: true,
}).clear();
```

How do I successfully remove the event listener? I can't just name the instances, that will be so messy in the long run when setting and removing the scroll events from various different places.

Comment: Do you really need to support IE8? Because if not, your `addEvent` function is completely unnecessary. IE9+ and everything else support `addEventListener`.

Comment: In real life removeEventListener removes a listener by the pointer in memory which is quite the same with the one which was used before in addEventListener. As I can see, you try to remove `scrollRoute[func]()` which is not the same with `()=>{
            scrollRoute[func](elem, funcOptions);
        }`. And yes, you need not to call the function when you remove a listener, so no need to use `()` after `scrollRoute[func]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder IE 8 is going to be very popular in 2020

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 - Huh? Is that meant as a joke?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes of course it is :D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, right now I have a deadline 1. Jan and I have mostly anything ready except bugs like the one stated above:'D still haven't solved lol :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You have to pass the **same** function to `removeEventListener` as you passed to `addEventListener`. (Similarly, you have to pass the same function to `detachEvent` as you passed to `attachEvent` using Microsoft's proprietary stuff — but unless you really have to support IE8 and earlier, you can ditch all that.) Your code isn't doing that.
2. When trying to remove the handler, you're **calling** `scrollRoute[func]()` and passing its return value into `removeEventListener`. As far as I can tell, that's passing `undefined` into `removeEventListener`, which won't do anything useful.

Here's the code I'm referring to above:

```
this.events = () => {
    addEvent(elem, 'scroll', ()=>{               // *** Arrow function you don't
        scrollRoute[func](elem, funcOptions);    // *** save anywhere
    }, flag);                                    // ***
}
this.clear = () => {
    elem.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollRoute[func](), flag);
// Calling rather than passing func −−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Notice that the function you're passing `addEvent` (which will pass it to `addEventListener`) is an anonymous arrow function you don't save anywhere, but the function you're passing `removeEventListener` is the result of **calling** `scrollRoute[func]()`.

You'll need to keep a reference to the function you pass `addEvent` and then pass that **same** function to a function that will undo what `addEvent` did (`removeEvent`, perhaps?). Or, again, ditch all that, don't support IE8, and use `addEventListener` directly.

So for instance:

```
var scrollHandler = function(options) {
    var func = options.func.name;
    var funcOptions = options.func.options;
    var elem = options.elem;
    var flag = options.flag;
    var handler = () => {
        scrollRoute[func](elem, funcOptions);
    };

    this.events = () => {
        elem.addEventListener('scroll', handler, flag);
    };
    this.clear = () => {
        elem.removeEventListener('scroll', handler, flag);
    };
};
```

*(Notice I added a couple of missing semicolons, since you seem to be using them elsewhere, and consistent curly brace positioning.)*

Or using more features of ES2015 (since you're using arrow functions already):

```
var scrollHandler = function(options) {
    const {elem, flag, func: {name, options}} = options;
    const handler = () => {
        scrollRoute[name](elem, options);
    };

    this.events = () => {
        elem.addEventListener('scroll', handler, flag);
    };
    this.clear = () => {
        elem.removeEventListener('scroll', handler, flag);
    };
};
```

Comment: I used addEventListener directly, but I am still not able to remove the event listener, I'm a bit confused as to how to do this and how to do it dynamically

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 - Again, the main thing is to use the same function. I've added an example above.

Comment: Hi T.J, I see and thanks for everything, I copied your whole function, but it does still not remove the scroll event when trying to call 'clear'


        new scrollHandler({
            func: {
                'name':'contentScroll',
            },
            elem: window,
            flag: true
        }).clear();

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 - It has to be the **same** instance of `scrollHandler`, not a new different instance. Again: The function passed to `remoteEventListener` has to be the **same one** passed to `addEventListener`. (BTW: If you're using `new` with it, `scrollHandler` should start with an upper case character.)

Comment: I tried adding it like this         let contentScroll = new scrollHandler({
            func: {
                'name':'contentScroll',
            },
            elem: window
        }).events();

calling the contentScroll.clear() from within my other function that has to clear the scroll event... but it says its not defined lol xD i give up on javascript :D